# Migrating RequireJS/AMD with Plugins to Webpack

Tags: requirejs, migrate, webpack-3, requirejs-text

I'm working on migrating a large RequireJS application to Webpack. The basic build with Webpack seems to work fine -- I've moved "paths" definitions to "alias" and I've setup loaders for my content and shims, like jQuery.

However, there's a remaining issue I'm not sure how to resolve. Basically the RequireJS app uses the "text-plugin" to include HTML templates, and Webpack is throwing "Module not found" errors for the HTML templates.

An example AMD module I want to bundle looks something like this:

**AMD Module with Text Plugin**

```
define([
   'security',
   'modals',
   'text!../templates/contact_info.html'
], function(security, modals, contactInfoTemplate) {
   return {
      foo: function() { return "bar"; }
   };
});
```

I *thought* I could use the raw-loader to load the template files. I aliased 'text' to be the 'raw-loader':

```
text: {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: "raw-loader"
      },
```

However, I'm seeing the following error for all of my templates that are required like above:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'text'
BREAKING CHANGE: It's no longer allowed to omit the '-loader' suffix when using loaders. You need to specify 'text-loader' instead of 'text'.
```

I tried replacing 'text!...' with 'text-loader!...', and I then see this error complaining that it can't load/find the HTML module!

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../templates/contact_info.html'
```

**webpack.config.js, version 3.9.1**

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

let basePath = path.join(__dirname, '/');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    'main': basePath +  'js/main.js',
  },
  context: __dirname,
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/build',
    filename: '[name].min.js',
    libraryTarget: 'amd',
    umdNamedDefine: true
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /(\.js)$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        use: {
          // babel-loader to convert ES6 code to ES5 + amdCleaning requirejs code into simple JS code, taking care of modules to load as desired
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
            plugins: []
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          { loader: "style-loader" },
          { loader: "css-loader" }
        ]
      },
      { test: /\.jpg$/, use: [ "file-loader" ] },
      { test: /\.png$/, use: [ "url-loader?mimetype=image/png" ] },
      {
        test: /\.(html)$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'raw-loader',
          options: {
            minimize: true
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: [
      'js/**/*.js',
      'node_modules',
      path.resolve('./js')
    ],
    extensions: ['.js'], // File types,
    alias: {
      text: {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: "raw-loader"
      },
      bridge: 'libs/bridge',
      cache: 'libs/cache',
      cards: 'libs/cards',
      moment: 'libs/moment',
      underscore: 'libs/underscore',
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist']),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: 'index.html',
      template: '../index.html'
    }),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery'
    })
  ]
};
```

Anyone know how to get Webpack to play nicely with the RequireJS Text plugin?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try installing `text-loader`?

In order for something like `'text!../templates/contact_info.html'` to "load" properly, since it is not JS, you need to install `text-loader` to get webpack to understand the syntax `text!`.

`npm install text-loader --save-dev`

humm...i just installed `text-loaded` and it seems we also have to change `text!` to `text-loader!`

Comment: This works for me, but I have to add 
`resolveLoader: { alias: { text: 'text-loader' } }`